# SimpleXML xpath within selected node

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I have the following XML file

```
<Item> 
  <name>...</name>
  <id>...</id>   
  <ImageSets>    
    <ImageSet Category="variant">
      <SwatchImage>
        <URL>...</URL>
        <Height Units="pixels"></Height>
        <Width Units="pixels"></Width>
      </SwatchImage>
      <SmallImage>
        <URL>...</URL>
        <Height Units="pixels"></Height>
        <Width Units="pixels"></Width>
      </SmallImage>
    </ImageSet>

    <ImageSet Category="primary">
      <SwatchImage>
        <URL>...</URL>
        <Height Units="pixels"></Height>
        <Width Units="pixels"></Width>
      </SwatchImage>
      <SmallImage>
        <URL>...</URL>
        <Height Units="pixels"></Height>
        <Width Units="pixels"></Width>
      </SmallImage>
    </ImageSet>
  </ImageSets>
</Item>

<Item>....</Item>
```

Then I use PHP to iterate through Item nodes within file.

```
foreach ($Xml as $item){
    $name = $item->name;
    $ID = $item->id;
};
```

And so on. The code works perfect extracting names and Id's for every item.

Now my problem is to extract ImageSet Category='primary'->SmallImage->URL. ImageSet nodes do not go in any particular order, so sometimes 'primary' will be first, sometimes 'variant', that's why `$item->ImageSets->ImageSet[1]` is not a solution

So within my main foreach loop I've tried using xpath as follows:

```
$src='';    
foreach ($item->ImageSets->xpath('//ImageSet[@Category="primary"]') as $img){
    $src = $img->MediumImage->URL;
};
```

With absolutely no luck.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Realtive to your context node $item (I have no doubt there's why you need that context node ;-)) you're looking for ImageSet that a) is a child of ImageSets (which in turn is a direct child of your context node) and b) has the attribute Category with the value `primary` (which you have coded correctly)

```
<?php
$itemset = new SimpleXMLElement(data());
foreach ($itemset as $item) { // or something else - just some reason why you have to work with $item
    foreach ($item->xpath('ImageSets/ImageSet[@Category="primary"]') as $p) {
        echo $p->SwatchImage->URL;
    }
}


function data() {
    return <<< eox
<ItemSet>
    <Item>
      <name>...</name>
      <id>...</id>
      <ImageSets>
        <ImageSet Category="variant">
          <SwatchImage>
            <URL>...</URL>
            <Height Units="pixels"></Height>
            <Width Units="pixels"></Width>
          </SwatchImage>
          <SmallImage>
            <URL>...</URL>
            <Height Units="pixels"></Height>
            <Width Units="pixels"></Width>
          </SmallImage>
        </ImageSet>
        <ImageSet Category="primary">
          <SwatchImage>
            <URL>primary swatch image url</URL>
            <Height Units="pixels"></Height>
            <Width Units="pixels"></Width>
          </SwatchImage>
          <SmallImage>
            <URL>...</URL>
            <Height Units="pixels"></Height>
            <Width Units="pixels"></Width>
          </SmallImage>
        </ImageSet>
      </ImageSets>
    </Item>
    <Item>...</Item>
</ItemSet>      
eox;
}
```

Comment: Great slution, hovewer I've found another one : foreach ($item->ImageSets->ImageSet as $img){
     foreach ($img->attributes() as $a=>$b){
      if ($b == 'primary'){
       $src = $img->MediumImage->URL;
       echo $src;
       }
      }
     };  Just wondering which one would be faster?

Comment: Performance->don't guess, but measure. But I have a hunch that _not_ doing the iterations and comparisons "within" the script will be faster.

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in the XPath expression. If the expression starts with an `/` it is relative to the document itself. You want it relative to the current node. This means you have two possible solutions

### `ImageSet[@Category="primary"]`

This expands to `child::ImageSet`. It fetches the `ImageSet` element nodes that are direct children of the context node.

### `.//ImageSet[@Category="primary"]`

Expands and normalizes to `descendant::ImageSet`. It fetches any `ImageSet` inside the current context, even if it is not a direct child. The `.` represents the current node and `//` changes the axis to descendants.